# Creating a Test Facebook app with publish action permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I see that Facebook has made a lot of changes in their API and working structure of those for creating the FB application for Web/IOS/Mobile.

I am creating a facebook app with my FB developer account to get the Test App's API secret credentials.

With this app I need to test the feature of Publish_ations (Ex:- Post on pages/wall,sharing),but that feature is not enabled for Test App API.And if we want to enable that then we may have to submit the review with some details.In those details they are asking for the steps to test the feature that we will provide in our Application.They need the snaps of pages where that FB feature will be and ETC of info.And that whole process will take upto 7 days.

I am confused that if my application is in progress and that FB feature we are planning to develope then How should I give the steps to test the Feature on our website before creation of that Feature.

Is there any information that I am missing from FB docs for testing enviornment with Publish Action permission.

Please help me I have already wasted 7 days (Tried the review submission process of FB and they have rejected that because of incomplete application and information)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confused. The login/permissions related things **works as it was in v1.0** ; just the difference is that you need to submit for [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) after the app is ready. But that's the **last step**.

I think you're using the API for the first time, so you may not be aware how exactly to add the permissions in your app. The permissions are added using the `scope` parameter in the login code. [See the details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0)..

For example, if you're using the JS SDK-

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

similarly its done for the other languages.

After adding the permission the admin/developers/testers of the app **can test** the application and publish posts; while app is in development mode. And this is just similar how we used to do in v1.0.

When your app is ready (the last step), submit your app for the [login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) (this step wasn't present in the v1.0, you just needed to make it live). After they approve your app with this permission, you can make your app live and everybody can publish post using your app. That's it.

Comment: your comment give me a clue to see again in my setting and I found that I was using publish_stream in my scope instead of "publish_actions".
Thanks :)

Comment: But how can I add functionality to live site so as to facebook could verify it, but real users won't be able to use this functionality? - I don't think they wiil be satisfyied seing functionality but aren't be able to use it.